# get all features properties in d3

Tags: d3.js

How we can get all features properties in [D3](https://d3js.org/) with clicking on a feature?
For example, how we can get 'AREA' and 'PERIMETER' of all provinces of this map: [GeoJson map of Colombia](https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/43c7656821069d00dcbc), when clicking on a province?

The code below not work. I see 'properties' undefined.

```
function clicked(d) {
    var polys= effectLayer.selectAll("path");
    var x;
    var txt;

   for (x in polys) {
       //show this:
       txt += polys[x].properties.AREA + " ";
   }
   alert(txt );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaking a selection for a datum. You cannot access a selection like this:

```
polys[x].properties.AREA
```

So, since what you want is the datum, use an `each`:

```
var txt = "";
var polys= mapLayer.selectAll("path").each(function(e){
    txt += e.properties.AREA + " "
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks, check the console: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/bb29d8d5b984da7fc8079c94cce9423c/e9963b96e01b2ecab5215ecf31c7d821c6b54daf

Comment: Thank you a lot. But another question: provinces with AREA < 1000000 for example become yellow. if(e.properties.AREA  < 1000000) then e.style("attribute", "yellow"); or its visibility become hidden.

Comment: @Mohsen If you have a different issue please post a *new* question. But here is the hint: `e` is the datum, not the element!

Comment: OK. Can I refer to this post?

Comment: Sure: not only you can, actually you **should**! That way, users can see what's happening and have a bit of background.

Comment: @Mohsen I just saw your new question, and I can assure you it will get a lot of downvotes quickly. While you should link this present question, you have to explain the problem and give all the code details in the question itself, that is, the question has to be self-contained!