# change style of features in d3

Tags: d3.js

According to [get all features properties in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49873489/get-all-features-properties-in-d3), when clicking a province I want to change the visibility of provinces with area < 10000000 for example to hidden? Or its color to another color?

```
var polys= mapLayer.selectAll("path").each(function(e){
    if(e.properties.AREA < 10000000 )
      ???.style("visibility", "hidden");    
});
```

what can I use instead of ??? ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `d3.select(this)`

Comment: I get the reason for the downvotes for my answer in this question (answering to a non "self-contained" question). But isn't that description enough to answer it? I mean if someone is facing issue selecting a particular path in an `each` loop, shouldn't it be clear enough? I'm not arguing but just need a clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It seems "d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden");" should be correct. But nothing happened.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each

Comment: Use console to print the values of `e.properties.AREA` and condition the paths accordingly.

Comment: Excuse me for delay. Value of "e.properties.AREA" is correct.

Comment: In my old code, in the "<style>" of head section I set "visibility: hidden;" for some features. I changed "visibility: hidden;" to "visibility: visible;" and now "d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden");"  works well. But it's interesting when "visibility: hidden;", "d3.select(this).style("visibility", "visible");"  does not work.